# How to set different themes for multiple domains

Tags: theming, 8

I am developing a multi-domain site with same code base and single data base.
I am trying to set themes for multi domains which was previously supported by domains theme module in Drupal 7.
  Don't know how to achieve solution for this. Please help me for this.

Comment: Notice that you are merely stating facts without asking any explicit question (the question title doesn't count as that), which also include telling us what you tried and why it didn't work for you, where you looked at, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an solution that my colleague suggested through a contrib module.
But, not yet used it perfectly for themes.

`Steps for getting it are as follows -`
1. go to

> www.github.com
>   and sign up for free.
>   2. Take a git clone of the 
>   https://github.com/agentrickard/domain.git
>   in modules folder in your drupal code base.
>   3. Extend the module and try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is: https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/aloknarwaria/2691703 there is a module for that in drupal 8 if you are using domain module, but it is in sandbox mode currently.Go the code and explore.

Answer (score 0):

domain_theme_switch
Domain Theme Switch module for Drupal 8 community users.

- This module provide the administrator interface to manage the theme.
- The interface provide very basic setting to manage the theme
  against each domain.